# reactjs react-select initial data

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is it possible to set initial label for react-select ( [lib](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) ) ? 
I'm trying to set initial label with value and on click show options.

didn't found solution

Answer (score 0):

You should set your initial data from constructor. Look at this.

```
const genders = [{label:'Male',id:'1'},{label:'Female',id:'2'}];

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { gender: 1 };
```

}

important = you have to set id value for initial data .

and component

`<Select
    simpleValue
    options={genders}
    value={this.state.gender} 
    onChange={value => this.genderChange(value)} />`